# How to disable remote build cache with command line flag in gradle

Tags: gradle

I found `--no-build-cache` flag, but it disables remote and local cache.

I need to disable only remote. Is it possible?

buildCacheSettings.gradle

```
buildCache {
    local {
        enabled = true
    }
    remote(HttpBuildCache) {
        url = 'http://mycache/cache'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in command for that, but you can make your own. I have the same requirement for one of my projects and solved it like this:

```
ext.disableRemoteBuildCache = hasProperty('DISABLE_BUILD_CACHE_REMOTE') || System.getenv().containsKey('DISABLE_BUILD_CACHE_REMOTE')

buildCache {
    local(DirectoryBuildCache) {
        // ...
    }
    remote(HttpBuildCache) {
        enabled = !disableRemoteBuildCache
        // ...
        logger.info("Remote build cache configured with enabled: $enabled and url $url")
    }
}
```

Then either create an environment variable called `DISABLE_BUILD_CACHE_REMOTE` or run with `-PDISABLE_BUILD_CACHE_REMOTE`.